# How do i write a vba for a column that will always increase in value

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel spreadsheet in which one column I am entering and engine hours daily.  I need to set a VBA code which will act as a warning system to get the engine serviced.  I would like the cell to change colour to amber at say 300, a darker orange at 400 and red at 500.  I also need it to generate an email at 500.  The problem I have is that the column will always increase in value.  Once the email is sent at 500, it will need to reset to 800, 900 and 1000 and so on.  Is this at all possible to do?

Thanks in advance.
Trace

Comment: Yes, this is possible with VBA.

Comment: through some combination of named ranges and/or customer data/xml and VBA, this is certainly possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried much. I know how to write a vba once a cell gets to a less than value see below, but I don't know where to start writing this one as the value keeps increasing Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("M4:M368"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 1000 Then
            Call Fuel_LevelW01D
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Comment: I've tried the conditional formatting, but it won't automatically increase the value

Comment: You don't have to change the number your using if you just work with the mod of the number. So your condition format formula would be `=Mod(A1,500)=300` then Amber, `=Mod(A1,500)=400` darker orange, `=Mod(A1,500)=0` then Red.

Comment: Thanks David, that's brilliant.  Can i now send an email automatically when it gets to Red?

Comment: @user3186437 I have updated my answer with the Worksheet change event you can use assuming you have outlook and know how to use a worksheet change event.

Comment: Thanks, yes i'm using outlook and i can use a worksheet change event.  This works perfect.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment earlier you could accomplish this with a formula based conditional format:

[image]

To have an email send automatically you could modify the following VBA to your specifications:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oMail As Object
If Target.Column = 1 Then 'If the change was made in your entry column
    If Target.Value Mod 500 = 0 Then
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
            With oMail
                .To = "YouRecipient@TheirDomain.com, Sample@Gmail.com"
                .Subject = "Engine Service Needed"
                .Body = "The engine mileage is currently at " _
                        + CStr(Target.Value) _
                        + " Miles And Needs to be Serviced"
                .Display 'You can replace the word display with the word send if you don't want to preview
            End With
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

***Update From Comment:***

```
For Amber change the formula to `=MOD(A1,500)>0`
For darker orange use `=MOD(A1,500)>300`
And for Red use `=OR(MOD(A1,500)>400,MOD(A1,500)=0)`
```

Comment: thanks, i have been using this, however, i now realise, i need to make it a 3 colour scale as it will only change colour if i type in the specific figure. ie 300, 400 500 etc.  Are you able to advise a new format.  I'd be happy to show you the spreadsheet i'm working on if that would help - i'm unsure how to though

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by that.

Comment: sorry.  i would like the colours to change gradually.  0-300 is blue 300-399 amber 400 - 500 is red.  I tried to copy and paste the worksheet into my comment to show you, but it didn't work

Comment: @Trace Answer has been updated.